# ¿Como obtener registros en un rango de fechas en codeigniter 4?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-4

tengo dos tablas, una guardo la relación entre pacientes y doctor, en la otra guardo las consultas medicas que puede existir entre una relación médico y paciente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esta es la configuracion de tabla nextconsulta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en Mysql realizo esta consulta

```
select nextconsulta.* from  apiconsultorio.nextconsulta
    left join relacion  ON relacion.idrelacion=nextconsulta.idrelacion
    where relacion.doctor='365227eb8bcb2c5b9732b6c01d0ec5d8'
    and nextconsulta.nextconsulta >= now() and nextconsulta.nextconsulta <= CURRENT_DATE() + 1
```

y obtengo correctamente que solo existen 2 registros.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando trato de replicar la consulta en Codeigniter 4 de esta forma

```
public function estadisticas($id){
        $db      = \Config\Database::connect();
        helper('date');

        $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $date1= date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date))) . " 00:00:00";

        $builder=$db->table("nextconsulta");

        $builder->select("nextconsulta.*")
            ->join('relacion', 'relacion.idrelacion=nextconsulta.idrelacion','left')
            ->where('nextconsulta.nextconsulta >=', $date)
            ->where('nextconsulta.nextconsulta <=', $date1)
            ->where('relacion.doctor', $id);
        $consulta = $builder->countAll();


        $response["date"]=$date;
        $response["date1"]=$date1;
        $response["consultas"]=$consulta ;
        return $this->response->setStatusCode( 200 )->setJSON( $response );
    }
```

la respuesta obtenida es la siguiente:

```
{
    "date": "2020-09-27 11:37:54",
    "date1": "2020-09-28 00:00:00",
    "consultas": 3,
}
```

y deberia dar respuesta 2.

Comment: te propongo eliminar los where de las fechas y compartirnos que devuelve

Comment: @EdelRojas aplique tu cambio y nos devuleve lo mismo `{
    "date": "2020-09-27 13:15:55",
    "date1": "2020-09-28 00:00:00",
    "consultaspendientes": 3
}`

Comment: prueba la funcion countAllResults(), me parece que countAll() es para el numero de la filas de tabla y como son 3 filas en tu tabla x eso devuelve 3.

Comment: `{
    "date": "2020-09-27 13:38:09",
    "date1": "2020-09-28 00:00:00",
    "consultaspendientes": 0
}` en este caso me devuelve cero registros

Comment: utiliza  $builder->getCompiledSelect(); y comparte el resultado

Comment: `{
    "date": "2020-09-27 14:04:18",
    "date1": "2020-09-28 00:00:00",
    "consultaspendientes": "SELECT `nextconsulta`.*\nFROM `nextconsulta`\nLEFT JOIN `relacion` ON `relacion`.`idrelacion`=`nextconsulta`.`idrelacion`\nWHERE `nextconsulta`.`nextconsulta` >= '2020-09-27 14:04:18'\nAND `nextconsulta`.`nextconsulta` <= '2020-09-28 00:00:00'\nAND `relacion`.`doctor` = 'c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c'"
}`

Comment: el codigo del doctor ='c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c' es diferente. esta cambiado en la bd?

Comment: @EdelRojas te envie la consulta equivocada, esta es la respuesta real....`"consultaspendientes": "SELECT `nextconsulta`.*\nFROM `nextconsulta`\nLEFT JOIN `relacion` ON `relacion`.`idrelacion`=`nextconsulta`.`idrelacion`\nWHERE `nextconsulta`.`nextconsulta` >= '2020-09-27 14:19:22'\nAND `nextconsulta`.`nextconsulta` <= '2020-09-28 00:00:00'\nAND `relacion`.`doctor` = '365227eb8bcb2c5b9732b6c01d0ec5d8'",`

Comment: Coincide el doctor

Comment: @EdelRojas si cambio a `$builder->get()->getResult();` el resultado es `"consultaspendientes": [ {"idrelacion": "1","nextconsulta": "2020-09-27 19:00:00" }` .me devuelve un solo registro que es lo real en este caso porque el anterior de las 2 dela tarde ya ocurrio, si le hago  `$consultaspendientes = $builder->countAll();` devuelve `"consultaspendientes": 3,` cuenta todos los registros de la tabla, no devuelve la cantidad que realmente cumplen con la condicion

Comment: bueno perfecto ya esta correcto.  si countAll() como te comente devuelve todas las filas de la tabla. countAllResults() deberia devolverte 1 en este caso.

Comment: @EdelRojas curioso este detalle que te comparto ahora, cuando hago la consulta por el navegador a codeigniter con `$consultaspendientes = $builder->countAllResults();` la respuesta es: `"consultaspendientes": 0`, pero si la hago usando la herramienta Postman,la respuesta es: `"consultaspendientes": 1`, creo que esto seria tema de otro debate, por ahora solucionado el problema

Comment: si lo haces asi $builder->countAllResults(false) ??

Comment: @EdelRojas sigue dando como resultado 0, gracias por la ayuda

Comment: No coloques solucionado al título, en vez de eso cuando el sistema te lo permita acepta tu propia respuesta y con eso basta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La respuesta correcta sugerida por @EdelRojas esla siguiente:

```
public function estadisticas($id){

$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$date1= date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date))) . " 00:00:00";

$builder=$this->db->table("nextconsulta");
$builder->select("nextconsulta.*");
$builder->join('relacion', 'relacion.idrelacion=nextconsulta.idrelacion','left');
$builder->where('nextconsulta.nextconsulta >=', $date);
$builder->where('nextconsulta.nextconsulta <=', $date1);
$builder->where('relacion.doctor', $id);
$consultaspendientes = $builder->countAllResults();

$response["consultaspendientes"]=$consultaspendientes ;
return $this->response->setStatusCode( 200 )->setJSON( $response );
```

}

arroja estos resultados

```
{
    "consultaspendientes": 1,
   }
```